# Adding <pre> causes table cell to BLOW UP?

Tags: html, jsp, tags

im using "pre" tags in order to allow a textarea box to pass over newlines because Im stripping html out the form when its subitted.  The problem is with adding the "pre"...my table cell expands to enournous proportions and I dont know why.....

Thanks in advance

Before pre tag:

[image]

after pre tag:

[image]

Heres the code for that table:

```
<form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" action="" method="post">
<ctl:vertScroll height="300" headerStyleClass="data_table_scroll" bodyStyleClass="data_table_scroll" enabled="${user.scrollTables}">
<ctl:sortableTblHdrSetup topTotal="false" href="show.whatif_edit_entry?entryId=${entry.entryId}"/>
<table class="data_table vert_scroll_table" style="width:360px;">
    <tr>
    <ctl:sortableTblHdr styleClass="center" title="Comments" property="comment" type="top">Comments</ctl:sortableTblHdr>    
    <ctl:sortableTblHdr styleClass="center" title="Created By" property="auditable.createdBy.lastName" type="top">Entered By</ctl:sortableTblHdr>

    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="comments" items="${entry.comments}">


    //PRE HERE!!    ----->>>   <tr id="id${comments.id}">
           <td id="comments-${comments.id}"  style="width:360px;"><pre>${comments.comment}</pre></td>

        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${comments.auditable != null}">
        <td title="${comments.auditable.createdBy.lastName},  ${comments.auditable.createdBy.firstName} on 
            <fmt:formatDate value="${comments.auditable.createdDate}" pattern="${date_time_pattern}" />"><span class="mouseover_text">${comments.auditable.createdBy.lastName}, ${comments.auditable.createdBy.firstName} on 
        <fmt:formatDate value="${comments.auditable.createdDate}" pattern="${date_time_pattern}" />
        </td>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
        <td  colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        </tr> 
    </c:forEach>

    <c:if test="${lock.locked || form.entryId < 0 }">

    <%-- This is the row for adding a new comment. --%>           

        <tr id="commentRow">              
         <td>
         You have <strong><span id="commentsCounter">${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH'] - fn:length(commentForm.comment)}</span></strong> characters left.<br/>
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="2" cols="125" style="width:320px;"
                 onkeypress="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                 onkeydown="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                 onkeyup="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"></textarea>

                    <a href="javascript:addComment();"><img src="../images/icon_add.gif" border="0" alt="Add"/></a>
        </td>
        <td class="shaded" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

    </c:if>
</table>
```

```
pre
{
white-space: pre-wrap;                  /* css-3 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
word-wrap: break-word;                  /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
width: 99%;
}
```

Comment: Better yet...which particuly css function you want to see?

Comment: Do you modify the pre element at all in your css?

Comment: I added what I found in the css under "pre"...I normally just write the java stuff...so im not that good with styling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is: `width: 99%;` in `pre`. Remove that line.

Comment: thats what i was thinking..however...there are 3 other pages in the code base that are using "pre" tags....can I add something to the css just to use on this page??

Comment: What Christopher said. Add a class to your table `small_pre` for example: `<table class="small_pre"`> and in your css: `table.small_pre pre {width:auto;}` Make sure that line comes AFTER the `pre {width: 99%}` statement or use `!important` to override it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't (ab)use `<pre>`. Just use `<c:out>` to HTML-escape user-controlled input to prevent XSS.

```
<c:out value="${comments.comment}" />
```

Comment: we cant use <c:out> anymore...i actually went throught the entire code base 2 months ago and removed all 15,000 occurences of that

Comment: Then you have caused a major problem. Whenever you redisplay user-controlled data plain vanilla in JSP without `<c:out>` or `fn:escapeXml()`, then you've created a big XSS hole. Why did you remove those tags? Was it ignorance?

Comment: Hey..the principal developers make the decisions..I just push the buttons...lol

Comment: Complain at them. It was a stupid decision. You, on the other hand, should also have known that better and complain beforehand that it would only create XSS holes. Anyway, if you have proper content version management, just rollback the changes. It's also a matter of just a button press.

Comment: But check this out for this situation...I added this in our ajax folder ' form.setComment(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(bean.getComment()));'

Comment: had i not added that...they could inject javascript in that textarea and have it execute on page reload....

Comment: Did you also do that for 15,000 other occurrences? It's actually the wrong place to escape HTML. It should be done in the view side, using `<c:out>`. The DB could have been externally modified, for example. Escaping JavaScript is also to be done with `<c:out>`. The `<script>` will then just be printed as `&gt;script&lt;` and do absolutely no harm.

Comment: its been 2 months with no issues....come to think of it..removing those '<c:out>' was the first task I was given...the code is very funky here...

Comment: we dont want text written out to the user like that...we def dont want it in the databse written like that..

Comment: This is sad, very sad. Good luck further with the project.

Comment: It's not that big of a deal, really. `<c:out>` is the proper way, but I'm sure `pre` would suffice (not to mention if they're doing it the wrong way, they probably don't have that many people using it anyways).